# Rotate button's background image

Tags: android, image, button, rotation

I set an image to  `FloatingActionButton`. Now, when the `fab` is clicked the background button will start rotating.

I did image rotation using this code

imgview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.rotate);

```
anim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, 360.0f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF,
        .51111112f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
anim.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
anim.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE); 
anim.setDuration(1500);
imgview.startAnimation(anim);
```

But can't rotate `fab` background image.

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

i think you are using  `android:background=""` use this `android:src=""`
here is the example

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end" android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

and set clicklistener for fab button

Comment: Yes, I did this for `fab`. But my question is how to rotate the image when the `fab` is clicked?